header stamp time not updating
I ran into some problems getting nav2 working, during debugging I found that most of the header stamp times stay the same for each new message. I've been running some simulation to practice and test with slam toolbox and nav2 which goes fine. The problem comes when I try to run everything on a real robot, some errors occurred which lead to finding the header stamp times issue.
I did my testing on a raspberry pi 4, it's running ROS2 humble and ubuntu server 22.04 and a laptop that also runs ubuntu and ros2 humble.
I have a setup that can do slam toolbox mapping on async online, this setup is a customized ros2 controllers example 2, a lidar package, rf2o odometry package and slam toolbox. This setup is run for all packages with use_sim_time false.
I found that the header stamp time for the following doesn't change:
/scan                  (from lidar package)
/tf of odom->base_link (from rf2o package)
/tf of map->odom       (from slam toolbox)

The header stamp time for the following do update for each new message:
/tf left wheel joint  (from customized example 2)
/tf right wheel joint (from customized example 2)

I downgraded to only running the lidar package for easier debugging, the header stamp is the time of starting the node, and this stamp time is then in every message send. I tested this on the raspberry pi4 and on the laptop, both setups act the same.
The test setup is as follows, first I start my lidar package for the camsense x1:
source install/setup.bash
ros2 run camsense_ros2_driver camsense_publisher

Next I echo the /scan topic:
ros2 topic echo /scan

The echo from this shows the following, to not just do page filling I removed the ranges and intensities data and just copy paste the header data:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1722026253
    nanosec: 114990118
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: 0.0
angle_max: 6.267477512359619
angle_increment: 0.015707964077591896
time_increment: 0.00047753838589414954
scan_time: 0.0010000000474974513
range_min: 0.07999999821186066
range_max: 8.0
ranges:
- x.x
- '...'
intensities:
- y.y
- '...'
---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1722026253
    nanosec: 114990118
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: 0.0
angle_max: 6.267477512359619
angle_increment: 0.015707964077591896
time_increment: 0.00047735098632983863
scan_time: 0.0010000000474974513
range_min: 0.07999999821186066
range_max: 8.0
ranges:
- x.x
- '...'
intensities:
- y.y
- '...'
---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1722026253
    nanosec: 114990118
  frame_id: laser
angle_min: 0.0
angle_max: 6.267477512359619
angle_increment: 0.015707964077591896
time_increment: 0.00047748585348017514
scan_time: 0.0010000000474974513
range_min: 0.07999999821186066
range_max: 8.0
ranges:
- x.x
- '...'
intensities:
- y.y
- '...'
---

From this it can be seen that in the header stamp the 'sec' and 'nanosec' times stay the same with every new published message.
The driver for the lidar is the formigola90/camsense_ros2_driver on github.
The message is populated as:
sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan scan;
std_msgs::msg::Float32 rpmsMsg;
scan.header.stamp = now();
scan.header.frame_id = frame_id_;
scan.angle_increment = (2.0 * M_PI) / 400.0;
scan.angle_min = 0.0;
scan.angle_max = 2.0 * M_PI - scan.angle_increment;
scan.scan_time = 0.001;
scan.range_min = 0.08;  // camsense x1 spec
scan.range_max = 8;    // camsense x1 spec
scan.ranges.resize(400);;
scan.intensities.resize(400);;

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? With only the lidar package running there is no change of a simulated clock running and as far I understand the command now() then gets the value of the wall clock, which it does do 1 time but then keeps using the same stamp.
Thanks in advance. If you need any more information just let me know and I will update the question.

Can you edit this to provide a short reproducible example of your problem? You've loosely described a larger system where it's not clear what component is causing the issue.

I've added my short test setup with 3 consecutive echo's from /scan topic

That's helpful. Next is to look at how the laser driver is populating the field. What lidar driver are you using?

I added the driver info, the field is populated by scan.header.stamp = now();

Is this camsense_publisher linux process using >= 100% cpu?

No it doesn't come anywhere near 100% on both raspberry pi and laptop

It's not clear where your now() function is coming from. But you should be using a now on a clock object from the node which will be hooked up to the appropriate time source.
It should be more like node->get_clock()->now() or use the shorthand node->now()
Where you can cache the clock pointer if you're using it repeatedly.
API docs https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/p/rclcpp/generated/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#classrclcpp_1_1Node

I now understand that now() needs to be pointed to a source, but haven't been able to get this working yet. How can I see//know if a node is hooked up to an appropriate time source? I'm also wondering how the first timestamp is produced if currently there is no time source?

After creating my own node with clock hooked up to system time I could confirm that the issue was not to be found here. I found now() was used in a wrong location in the code, after finding the correct location all is working now.

Glad to hear that it's working for you!
